# Need a solution for 2D collision handling in Python

Tags: python, 2d, collision

I have a program written for simple 2D collision detection and handling on my current billiards simulation, however it is rubbish am looking for a solution that involves proper physics, i.e. newtons laws of motion for coliisions. what I have so far, which does not conserverve momentum and simplifies physics is

```
    def collide(ball1,ball2):
        dx = ball1.x - ball2.x
        dy = ball1.y - ball2.y

        dist = (dx)**2+(dy)**2
       if dist < (ball1.radius + ball2.radius)**2:

            tangent = atan2(dy, dx)
            angle = 0.5 * pi + tangent

            angle1 = 2*tangent - ball1.angle
            angle2 = 2*tangent - ball2.angle

            speed1 = ball2.speed*e
            speed2 = ball1.speed*e

            (ball1.angle, ball1.speed) = (angle1, speed1)
            (ball2.angle, ball2.speed) = (angle2, speed2)

            ball1.x += sin(angle)
            ball1.y -= cos(angle)
            ball2.x -= sin(angle)
            ball2.y += cos(angle)
```

and what i have to run the collisions is this, where the bounce() is for hitting against the wall

```
    running = True
    while running:
        background()

        for i,ball in enumerate(balls,1):
            ball.bounce()
            ball.move()
            for ball2 in balls[i:]:
                collide(ball,ball2)
            ball.display()


        pygame.display.flip()
```

i'm still pretty new to this so please change whatever is useless/stupid

Comment: Are you looking for suggestions for libraries that will do the 2d collision for you (or at least simplify things) or are you trying to write this from scratch for educational reasons (in which case you still may want to review the libraries source)

Comment: wll for educational reasons, it would be good to write from scratch , but i'm kind of new so i have no idea where to start. If there are any good libraries please point me there too thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recall I did a simple billiard simulator a while back. As you mentioned this is for educational purposes I will spare you from the whole code (and I don't have to dig around for it too :) )

But basically, I kept track of how long time has elapsed since the last frame. I used this time to find out new positions of each ball given a speed vector of each ball. For collisions in a frame I had to figure out at which exact time two balls would collide, and then apply each collision at that exact time. Pseudo code would look something like:

```
while running:
  frame_time_ms = time elapsed since last frame
  collisions = all collisions that will happen during this frame, with the exact time of collision. (1)
  while collisions:
    collision = first collision in collisions
    collision_time_ms = time of collision (1)
    move all balls to collision_time_ms
    collide the two balls in the collision (2)
    collisions = all remaining collisions after the time of collision (1)
  move all balls to the end time of the frame
```

So, you will need to bring back your geometry and physics knowledge to find out the key formulas to:

1. Given the start and end position of two balls in a frame (or part of
   a frame), do they collide, and at which point do they collide.
   Remember to include the radius of the balls as well here. This will
   give you the time of collision.
2. Given two balls at exact collision position, how will their new speed vectors look like afterwards. Some hints is to use elastic collisions, and experiment with how elastic it actually is:
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision For bonus points you
   could also include rotation of the balls :)

Good luck! =)

Answer (score 0):

Circle on circle collision is simple. Take the center point co ordinance, subtract them to determine the distance between each circle.

Then, if the distance is greater than the sum of both circles radii, than they do not touch. If it is equal they are touching, if it's less they are overlapping.

Simply, if they are touching, have them repel each other. You can do this in a few ways. If you keep track of the directions they move in, have them move in the opposite direction.

As for walls, just use each wall with > < statements. So if the pos of a circle has x coordinates less than the west wall, than it has passed that wall. Again, just have them repel the walls.

Circle Collison is very simple if however you want to do other shapes it will be unbelievably difficult. Unless you just pit circles around those shapes or use pixel perfect collision (this is very high performance demand.)

If you want highly accurate collision of non circles, get a physics engine.